# Unable to Alt+Tab more than once after recent update (Ubuntu Gnome 17.04)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell

After updating my packages to the newest update, and updating my gnome-shell extensions (I use the AlternateTab extension), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> no longer works as expected.

When pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it only switches to the next window. Clicking <kbd>Tab</kbd> more times after that does not do anything.

I do not know if this issue was caused by updating the AlternateTab extension or updating gnome-shell itself. It seems like it has to do with updating gnome-shell itself, because the issue persists when disabling the AlternateTab extension.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by:

1. Booting the Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Live CD
2. Mounting my file system (`sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt`)
3. Copying the extensions from the Live CD file system to my real file system (`sudo rsync -a /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ /mnt/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`)

I am guessing this had something to do with incompatible versions of the extension and gnome-shell but I am not sure.

**Edit:**

This is a simpler solution:
Since I updated the extension using Google Chrome, the updated version was saved in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and the original still existed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, therefore the issue can be solved by simply typing `rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/`